# How to strip characters from the right side of every word in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, strip

Say, if I have a text like

```
text='a!a b! c!!!'
```

I want an outcome like this:

```
text='a!a b c'
```

So, if the end of each words is '!', I want to get rid of it. If there are multiple '!' in the end of a word, all of them will be eliminated.

Comment: what if I have to get rid of quotes(') and double quotes("), not only (!)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
print " ".join(word.rstrip("!") for word in text.split())
```

Comment: This may return a different string if text contains tabs or varying spaces.

Comment: Simple fix for that, just use `text.split(' ')`

Comment: @jamylak that won't split on tabs which could be in a string

Comment: @Matt This all depended then, on the definition of a word

Comment: @jamylak I have never heard of a word that has a tab as a character in the word. I have only ever heard of tabs as word delimiters.

Comment: @Matt I was saying that people usually seperate words by spaces

Comment: what if I have to get rid of quotes(') and double quotes(")? " ".join(word.rstrip(""'") for word in text.split(' ')) doesn't work.

Comment: Should only remove *at the end of the string*

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the split/strip approach

```
" ".join(x.rstrip("!") for x in text.split())
```

which won't preserve whitespace exactly, you could perhaps use a regex such as

```
re.sub(r"!+\B", "", text)
```

which blanks out all exclamations that aren't immediate followed by the start of a word.

Comment: The regular expression you posted has problems with strings such as `a!!b`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
>>> testWord = 'a!a b! c!!!'
>>> re.sub(r'(!+)(?=\s|$)', '', testWord)
'a!a b c'
```

This preserves any extra spaces you may have in your string which does not happen with `str.split()`

Comment: Why do you use `\Z` instead instead of `$`?

Comment: @jamylak because for some reason I forgot about $, I updated it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regex, non-split based approach:

```
from itertools import groupby

def word_rstrip(s, to_rstrip):
    words = (''.join(g) for k,g in groupby(s, str.isspace))
    new_words = (w.rstrip(to_strip) for w in words)
    return ''.join(new_words)
```

This works first by using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group together contiguous characters based on whether or not they're whitespace:

```
>>> s = "a!a b! c!!"
>>> [''.join(g) for k,g in groupby(s, str.isspace)]
['a!a', ' ', 'b!', ' ', 'c!!']
```

Effectively, this is like a whitespace-preserving `.split()`.  Once we've got this, we can use `rstrip` as we always would, and then recombine:

```
>>> [''.join(g).rstrip("!") for k,g in groupby(s, str.isspace)]
['a!a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c']
>>> ''.join(''.join(g).rstrip("!") for k,g in groupby(s, str.isspace))
'a!a b c'
```

We can also pass whatever we like:

```
>>> word_rstrip("a!! this_apostrophe_won't_vanish these_ones_will'''", "!'")
"a this_apostrophe_won't_vanish these_ones_will"
```